# How do I create textfield with multiple line placeholder text

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I am getting issues when focusing on multiple lines of placeholder text fields the cursor overlaps with placeholder text while it is working fine with single-line.

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: question.fieldType == "textarea" ? 4 : 1,
  decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('${question.fieldLabel}')),
)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: question.fieldType == "textarea" ? 4 : 1,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: Text('${question.fieldLabel}'),
  ),
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
)
```

here the cursor will be positioned at the top of the text field, preventing it from overlapping with the placeholder text.

EDIT:
other possible solution.

```
  TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: question.fieldType == "textarea" ? null : 1,
      decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('${question.fieldLabel}')),
    )
```

and let us know any.

Comment: above solution is not working for me. @Rainy sidewalks.